# Foundation landscaping

Tags: landscaping, foundation

Last year I had the foundation of my house rebuilt and exterior drainage put on my property. The grass has taken ver and is now directly next to the foundation What can I or should I not do next to the foundation? Yes grass looks great growing all the way out there but a mower can’t get there & an edger will just destroy it so is it safe to go two feet out from the foundation and just put mulch there? If not what do I do?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/33469/20139